# Finding the corresponding bayesian network of a predefined joint probability distribution

Tags: algorithms, causality, joint-distribution, bayesian-network

Given a joint probability distribution over the variables $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$. Is there an algorithm for constructing the corresponding Bayesian Network?

Comment: I think you should be more specific about what your problem at hand is, and what you're trying to accomplish.  I think as your question is written, you are unlikely to get a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2):

First a quick note, since your question asks about "constructing the corresponding Bayesian network," singular rather than plural. In general, the joint distribution of $X_1,\dots,X_n$ doesn't determine a unique such structure, which makes sense, as the Bayesian network is intended to model causality, and a joint distribution in and of itself has nothing to say about that matter.

The directed acyclic graph involved is just a graphical representation of one [particular factorization of the joint distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model#Bayesian_network). Consider, say, two dependent variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. One factorization of the joint distribution is indicated by

$$\mathbb{P}(Y_1=y_1,Y_2=y_2) = \mathbb{P}(Y_1=y_1)\mathbb{P}(Y_2=y_2 \mid Y_1=y_1),$$

which would correspond to the DAG with an edge $Y_1 \longrightarrow Y_2$, but it could just as well be factorized with the roles of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ flipped, yielding the DAG with an edge $Y_2 \longrightarrow Y_1$. Their joint distribution is simply agnostic about the causal story.

All that said, there are indeed a variety of algorithms out there for (1) determining causal structures that are consistent (by some measure) with a given joint distribution, and (2) ranking or scoring such structures in terms of some fit. For instance, the SGS algorithm of Spirtes, Glymour and Scheines is a well-known algorithm that first identifies conditional independencies suggested by the data as constraints, and then looks for a structure that best satisfies those. Their book [*Causation, Prediction, and Search*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Causation_Prediction_and_Search.html?id=vV-U09kCdRwC) is the most exhaustive source for such things I  can think of (Chapters 5 and 6 in particular). A couple of other pointers:

- A [nice survey](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6925.pdf) that includes references to further sources on constraint-based algorithms as well as other approaches.
- [Lecture notes](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch25.pdf) from Cosma Shalizi that could be a nice way in to the SGS book.